# print out even numbers between two integers

Tags: c++

I need to create a function to print out even numbers between two integers

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;


int evens_between(int m, int n)
{
  for(int i = m; i<= n; i++)
  {
    if(i % 2 == 0)
     cout<<i<<" ";
  }
}


int main()
{
int m;
int n;

cin>>m>>n;
cout<<evens_between(m,n)<<endl;
return 0;
}
```

I'm getting error messages not sure if this is right though. Would appreciate some help understanding my error a little better

Comment: What is the error message? You're not returning any `int` value from your `evens_between` function.

Comment: You don't have to surround the evens_between call with cout and endl.

Comment: Please copy and paste your error messages into the question. Nobody else knows what they are.

Comment: Also when you need help please insert the error message in your question

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), take [the SO tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour), read about [how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/). And when asking question that involves errors, what *are* the errors? For build errors and warnings, always copy-paste the full and complete output into the question itself, and add a comment in the code on the line where the errors or warnings are.

Comment: What do you expect to happen if `m > n`?

Answer (score 2):

You're trying to print the function's result here:

```
cout<<evens_between(m,n)<<endl;
```

But that's wrong. Just call the function:

```
evens_between(m,n);
```

However, the error is because you're making the function return an `int`. At least you tell it to do so in its signature, it's not actually returning any value. Change it to `void` instead:

```
void evens_between(int m, int n)
```

Comment: thanks very much the teacher wants an int function  what would I do to change that

Comment: If your teacher says it is supposed to return an `int`, they probably told you what that return value should represent. Maybe the count of even numbers that got printed?

Comment: @BoBTFish  int evens_between(int n, int m) that returns the number of even numbers in between n and m

Comment: @user12230466 in that case you can put a counter that starts at `0` and increases every time you print a number, and when the loop is done, you return that counter.